# Create a S3 bucket on each AWS account created with terraform

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to create multiple AWS accounts using [aws_organizations_account](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account). What I am now trying to do is to create a aws_S3_bucket on each new created accounts.

```
resource "aws_organizations_account" "this" {
  for_each  = local.all_user_ids
  name      = "Dev Sandbox ${each.value}"
  email     = "${var.manager}+sbx_${each.value}@example.com"
  role_name = "Administrator"
  parent_id = var.sandbox_organizational_unit_id
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
}
```

Everything is working as expected for `aws_organizations_account` during my `terraform apply` but my S3 bucket is created inside my current AWS project while I am trying to create a S3 bucket for every new AWS account.

Comment: You would need to create a role with permission to create a bucket in the account and then assume the other account's role to create a bucket in the new account

Comment: How do I get the ID for every new account?

Comment: The `aws_organizations_account` returns the [id](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/organizations_account#id).

Comment: Thanks, but once I have this ID, how do I loop over those IDs on my aws_s3_bucket ressource?

Comment: Sure you can't loop, but it won't help you create those buckets in different accounts. TF does not have such a functionality. So its not clear what do you want to do? Also you have to tag @Marcin if you replying to commnets.

Comment: `provider "aws" {
  alias = "new_account"

  assume_role {
    role_arn     = "arn:aws:iam::${aws_organizations_account.new_account.id}:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
    session_name = "new_account_creation"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  provider = aws.new_account

  bucket = "new-account-bucket-${aws_organizations_account.new_account.id}"
  acl    = "private"
}` @Pierre-Alexandre, Could you please try using provider & resource  something like this?

Comment: Thanks @Mohan, let me try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Step 1:     `Create_terraform_s3_buckets.tf`

---

```
# First configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  access_key = var.aws_access_key
  secret_key = var.aws_secret_key
  region     = var.aws_region
}

// then use the resource block and create all the buckets in the variable array
// Here setup your accounts would in the variable for e.g. My_Accounts_s3_buckets      
variable "My_Accounts_s3_buckets" {
  type = list
  default = ["Testbucket1.app", "Testbucket2.app", "Testbucket3.app"]
}
```

---

Look up the s3_bucket objectfor more help from Terraform ref. [`aws_s3_bucket`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket)

```
 // resource "aws_s3_bucket" "rugged_buckets" "log_bucket" { <- different types of options on your buckets
 resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  count         = length(var.My_Accounts_s3_buckets) // here are you 3 accounts
  bucket        = var.My_Accounts_s3_buckets[count.index]
  acl           = "private"
  region        = "us-east-1"
  force_destroy = true

 tags = {
  Name        = "My Test bucket"
  Environment = "Dev"
 }

}
```

---

> ### Step 2: `You can now automate this with the variables file.`

```
# Make sure you keep this order

variable "My_Accounts_s3_buckets" {
  type = list
  default = ["mybucket1.app", 
             "mybucket2.app" // you can add more.. as needed                 
            ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's clear but I don't see anything related to aws_organizations_account which is my main issue